# UITableViewController vs UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

What all does `UITableViewController` get me that makes it actually useful? Is there any bonus is using it instead of just using a `UIViewController` for views with `UITableViews` in them? I ask because I want my views with `UITableViews` to inherit from a base view controller (which inherits from `UIViewController`). If I use a `UITableViewController` then having a base class for all my views becomes more difficult.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between UIViewController and UITableViewController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17305723/what-is-the-difference-between-uiviewcontroller-and-uitableviewcontroller)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Not much. It provides some conveniences, but you never really need it; I often don't use it.

The main things, aside from the automatic setup when you create one in the storyboard, are the three properties `tableView`, `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear`, and `refreshControl`. But they don't do anything you can't do yourself.

Comment: One more thing I've found that `UITableViewController` does that is pretty helpful is auto-adjusting the view when the keyboard covers a text field being edited. `Note: The UITableViewController class automatically resizes and repositions its table view when there is in-line editing of text fields.` - [Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)

Answer (score 7):

Well I do think both Retro and matt's answer are correct, from personal experience it is much easier and less "hackY" to use `UITableViewController` with `UIRefreshControl`, then trying to get UIRefreshControl work with UIViewController with a UITableView.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing more then the boilerplate code ready for setting the data source and connection to your tableView object, some getters and setter to make your life easy if you not want to put your effort to do the same thing which is available.

But in your case for SubClass its not fit to have `UItableViewController`